# What is the best approach OR pre-built web service for words-to-numbers conversion (for USD)?

Tags: web-services, nlp, text-processing, azure-language-understanding

For example: converting a string “three hundred dollars and twelve cents” to return “$300.12” back.

Siri does this well, but I can’t find open tools to do this. I'd like to parse numerical and monetary values from textual input returned from a Speech2Text service I'm currently using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming english, for Microsoft LUIS, prebuilt number, dimension, and money are good to include. LUIS will return more than one, if it matches. [Prebuilt Reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-reference-prebuilt-entities)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to Microsoft's `Recognizers-Text` project, hosted on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text).

It is available as a Nuget package for C# for example, or npm package for javascript.

Example ([.Net samples on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/.NET/Samples)):

```
// Currency recognizer will find any currency presented
// E.g "Interest expense in the 1988 third quarter was $ 75.3 million" will return "75300000 Dollar"
NumberWithUnitRecognizer.RecognizeCurrency(query, culture);
```